# Env variables with Jelastic Spring Boot

Tags: jelastic

I'm using the new Spring Boot node in Jelastic.

Previously under a Tomcat node I had;

```
server/variables.conf
-Dspring.profiles.active=sandbox
```

Now under the Spring Boot node the default is;

```
conf/variables.conf
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms32M -Xmn30M -Xmx1638M -Xminf0.1 -Xmaxf0.3  -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseCompressedOops"
```

Question is, where do I put my "-Dspring.profiles.active=sandbox"?

Adding it into the export line like so doesn't seem to work?

```
conf/variables.conf
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dspring.profiles.active=sandbox -Xms32M -Xmn30M -Xmx1638M -Xminf0.1 -Xmaxf0.3  -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseCompressedOops"
```

Nor on a line of its own.
Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah figured it out; [some shells don't allow dots](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/AbstractEnvironment.html#ACTIVE_PROFILES_PROPERTY_NAME)!

So solution now looks like;

```
conf/variables.conf
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dspring.profiles.active=sandbox -Xms32M -Xmn30M -Xmx1638M -Xminf0.1 -Xmaxf0.3  -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseCompressedOops"
export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=sandbox
```